# Powershell Export function to create environment variables with bash syntax

Tags: powershell

A lot of the time when working in DevOps, documentation and code snippets from colleagues will be based on bash.  Most of those same commands work seamlessly in PowerShell; but setting environment variables doesn't; e.g. `export DEMO_CLIENT_ID="ff3b7b84-e041-4e76-993e-239930808aa7"`.

I've written the below function so I can more easily just copy-paste these snippets and have them work without needing a rewrite:

```
Function Export {
    $regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::new('^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=(.*)$')
    $result = $regex.Match(($args -join ' '))
    if (!$result.Success) {
        throw "Could not set an environment variable based on [$($args -join ' ')]"
    }
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($result.Groups[1].Value, $result.Groups[2].Value)
}
```

This works well for most real world examples I've hit so far... but I'm sure there are gotchas lurking (e.g. I know that multiple spaces will be squashed to a single space when the split arguments are re-joined... which may be an issue in some scenarios).

Is there a better approach to this, or are there improvements I can make to avoid this and similar/unforeseen pitfalls?

Note: I know the function name doesn't meet best practices (i.e. verb-noun naming)... My only use case for this function is to simulate the `export` command; so I figured giving it a verb noun name and then aliasing that was just adding complexity with no benefit.

Comment: I've also submitted a suggestion to provide native support for `export` in pwsh: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20475

Comment: Where does this `DEMO_CLIENT_ID="ff3b7b84-e041-4e76-993e-239930808aa7"` string come from? What I mean: why not using the native hash table syntax: `Export @{ DEMO_CLIENT_ID="ff3b7b84-e041-4e76-993e-239930808aa7"; Name="Value" }`?

Comment: @iRon That's just an example of how one would assign a value to an environment variable in shell script.  I agree that a hash table would be a good approach if defining a new solution from scratch; but my aim is to make something that accepts the sorts of commands you see all over the web; e.g. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The PowerShell-idiomatic approach is to:

  - Define a command (function) that adheres to PowerShell's `<verb>-<noun>` naming convention, using one of the [approved verbs](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands).
  - Use an *alias* to provide another, typically shorter, name for the command, that isn't bound by this convention.
- Using `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), limiting the number of resulting tokens to `2`, allows you to split each name-value pair into its constituent parts, and the [`Env:` drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider) can be used to define a *process-scoped* environment variable for each pair.
- Given that the `export` builtin in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash accepts *multiple* `<name>=<value>` pairs (e.g. `export FOO='bar none' BAZ=2`), so does the function below.

  - *Caveat*: POSIX-compatible shells allow defining environment variables *without a value* (e.g. `export FOO`), which PowerShell and .NET do *not* support: assigning `$null` or `''`  invariably *undefines* (removes) an environment variable there.
    Therefore, the function below only accepts `<name>=<value>` pairs, and reports a *non-terminating error* if a given argument lacks an `=` or a value thereafter.

```bash
Set-Alias export Set-EnvironmentVariableByNameValuePair

function Set-EnvironmentVariableByNameValuePair {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [string[]] $NameValuePair
  )
  process {
    foreach ($pair in $NameValuePair) {
       $name, $value = $pair -split '=', 2
       if (-not $name -or -not $value) { Write-Error "Not in <name>=<value> format: `"$pair`". For technical reasons, you must supply a value."; continue }
       Set-Content Env:$name $value
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

- The above is more permissive than POSIX-compatible shells with respect to the *names* of environment variables - even though names that do not adhere to the constraints spelled out below *are* supported by the underlying platforms themselves.
- If you want to enforce the same name constraints that Bash does, insert the following before the `Set-Content` call:

  ```bash
  if ($name -notmatch '^[a-z_]\w*$') { Write-Error "Invalid name: $name"; continue }
  ```
- See also:

  - [GitHub issue #3316](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316), which asks for PowerShell to support the / something like the concise syntax that POSIX-compatible shells offer for defining *child-process-scoped* environment variables (e.g. `FOO='bar none' BAZ=2 some_utility ...`)

Comment: This is fantastic -- thank-you for improving it so much.  I wasn't aware of the multiple assignment option; great catch there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're quite right, the "export" name is just fine.

You started with an anchoring `^` caret -- kudos for that!

## non-greedy

```
([^=]+?)\s*=(.*)
```

We have a "lazy" `+?` in there.
I don't understand why.

Now, I will grant you that `export EQUATION=y-x=0`
potentially poses an issue, since second capturing group needs to be `y-x=0`.
But you *already* dealt with that, very nicely, using the "all but `=` equal-sign"
character class.
There's no danger of first group capturing `EQUATION=y-x`.
So the lazy `?` quantifier seems redundant.

This leaves the Gentle Reader speculating that maybe
the `\s*` optional whitespace match is relevant?
But with no visible suite of test strings it's hard to see what Author anticipated.
Please add a test suite.

Recommend you delete the lazy `?` quantifier.

That `\s*` optional whitespace match makes perfect sense.
Perhaps you would *also* like to strip leading blanks
that come after the `=` equal-sign?

It *is* possible for bash to define an empty env var, e.g. `$ export FOO=`.
But for your human-oriented use case, maybe you'd prefer `.+` over `.*` ?
So we will call out a truncated copy-n-paste with a fatal diagnostic message?

---

## quoting, interpolation

Sometimes documentation will say things like

```
$ export FOO="bar"
$ export FOO='baz'
$ export FOO=$PATH:/my/directory
```

I feel that stripping balanced double-quotes, or single-quotes, would be a win.

Emulating `$` dollar-sign interpolation might pose some challenges for you.
Consider raising fatal error when you see one.
The flip side is I have occasionally encountered credentials like this:

```
$ export VENDOR_API_SECRET='123speciaLcharacter$dollar*star'
```

(And then it's common enough to see wrong quoting produce `123speciaLcharacter*star`
on some production linux server.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Good point on the non-greedy piece already being taken care of by `[^=]`; my mistake.  Great point also on quotes and dollars... I'll have a think on how those work, as they've special meanings in both languages, so could be complicated...

Comment: I'll also add some examples for testing soon... great point. Getting late here now so probably won't be until tomorrow evening.